# how to set cookie for non logged in users to get the cart values form database in react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, local-storage

I am working on add to cart functionality.
I am making use of reactjs in front end and Nodejs with express in the backend.

I want to keep the cart for non logged in users in the database, as if I keep it in local storage it can be easily edited and all the original values get changed. But I am not getting how to identify the browser uniquely soo that I show them their corresponding cart whenever non logged in user visits website.
Can I get some guidance, please.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a sessionID that you store in local storage and in your database and with each request send the sessionID to verify the browser.